# Get test Path of a Grails Application

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I want to be able to fetch some files out of the "test" path of a Grails application.

Is there a framework call or API that I can leverage to obtain the path?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the following files

```
/test/unit/my/package/MyTest.groovy
/test/unit/my/package/resource.txt
```

You can read `resource.txt` from `MyTest.groovy` with

```
InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream('resource.txt)
```

or

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource('resource.txt)
```